# how to display FloorPlan of IndoorAtlas on Google Maps iOS - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I need to integrate IndoorAtlas with GMSMapView.

I displayed the floorPlan on the **GMSGroundOverlay** but its bounds it is not correct.

I am searching for the equivalent of **GroundOverlayOptions** in iOS.

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
IALatLng iaLatLng = floorPlan.getCenter();
LatLng center = new LatLng(iaLatLng.latitude, iaLatLng.longitude);
GroundOverlayOptions fpOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(bitmapDescriptor)
                .position(center, floorPlan.getWidthMeters(), floorPlan.getHeightMeters())
                .bearing(floorPlan.getBearing());
mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(fpOverlay);
```

I got the code from here : [IndoorAtlas in Google Maps Android](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/mapsoverlay/MapsOverlayActivity.java)

Any suggestions will be welcome.

[image: here is what I get before bearing]

[image: after bearing]

the icon must be inside the blue triangle.

```
-(void)changeMapOverlay2{
NSLog(@" ------> changeMapOverlay");
resultLogLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"------> changeMapOverlay"];

CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.topRight.latitude longitude:floorPlan.topRight.longitude];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.topLeft.latitude longitude:floorPlan.topLeft.longitude];
CLLocation *location3 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.bottomLeft.latitude longitude:floorPlan.bottomLeft.longitude];

CLLocationDistance meters = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
CLLocationCoordinate2D result1 = [self locationWithBearing:degreesToRadians(90) distance:meters fromLocation:location1.coordinate];
NSLog(@"meter %f from : ( %f, %f)", meters ,location1.coordinate.latitude , location1.coordinate.longitude);

meters = [location2 distanceFromLocation:location3];
CLLocationCoordinate2D result2 = [self locationWithBearing:degreesToRadians(0) distance:meters fromLocation:result1];
NSLog(@"meter %f from : ( %f, %f)", meters ,location2.coordinate.latitude , location2.coordinate.longitude);

GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(result2.latitude, result2.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.topRight.latitude, floorPlan.topRight.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(result1.latitude, result1.longitude)];

GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:path];
UIImage *icon = fpImage ;
GMSGroundOverlay *overlay = [GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithBounds:overlayBounds icon:icon];
overlay.bearing = floorPlan.bearing;
overlay.map = map;}
```

and here is the code how I draw the blue triangle using the coordinations of floorPlan.

```
-(void) drawFloorPlan{

GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.topLeft.latitude, floorPlan.topLeft.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.topRight.latitude, floorPlan.topRight.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.bottomLeft.latitude, floorPlan.bottomLeft.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.topLeft.latitude, floorPlan.topLeft.longitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.center.latitude, floorPlan.center.longitude)];

GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
rectangle.map = map;

/****************************/

CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.topRight.latitude longitude:floorPlan.topRight.longitude];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.topLeft.latitude longitude:floorPlan.topLeft.longitude];
CLLocation *location3 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:floorPlan.bottomLeft.latitude longitude:floorPlan.bottomLeft.longitude];

CLLocationDistance meters = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
CLLocationCoordinate2D result1 = [self locationWithBearing:degreesToRadians(90) distance:meters fromLocation:location1.coordinate];
meters = [location2 distanceFromLocation:location3];
CLLocationCoordinate2D result2 = [self locationWithBearing:degreesToRadians(0) distance:meters fromLocation:result1];

GMSMutablePath *path2 = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floorPlan.topRight.latitude, floorPlan.topRight.longitude)];
[path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(result1.latitude, result1.longitude)];
[path2 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(result2.latitude, result2.longitude)];

GMSPolyline *line = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path2];
line.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
line.map = map;}
```

Comment: You probably better off asking that to their online support.

Comment: @CeneCode I did but I am still waiting for the answer

Comment: show us what you have done ;)

Comment: the code -- and how would a square fit into a triangle?

Comment: @Daij-Djan the blue triangle is the right coordinations of the floorPlan.I use it for the bounds of the GMSGroundOverlay but the icon is outside the triangle

Comment: @NiibFouda Hii i too looking for the same Floor map into my mapview i dono how to achieve this plz reply back

Comment: @batMan007 can you check the answer below. I posted the solution. Also you can ask the online support. They are so interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
For everyone who wants to display the floorPlan of IndoorAtlas on Google Maps, here is the code.
 This is function to calculate the coordinates

```
-(NSArray *)calculateLongLatDegreesInMeters:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude {

float lat = M_PI * latitude / 180;

// Constants for calculating lengths
float m1 = 111132.92;
float m2 = -559.82;
float m3 = 1.175;
float m4 = -0.0023;
float p1 = 111412.84;
float p2 = -93.5;
float p3 = 0.118;

float eq1 = m1 + (m2 * cos(2 * lat)) + (m3 * cos(4 * lat));
float latitudeDegreeInMeters = eq1 + (m4 * cos(6 * lat));
float longitudeDegreeInMeters = (p1 * cos(lat)) + (p2 * cos(3 * lat)) +  (p3 * cos(5 * lat));

NSString *latDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitudeDegreeInMeters];
NSString *lonDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitudeDegreeInMeters];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:latDegInMtr,lonDegInMtr, nil];

return arr; //(latitudeDegreeInMeters, longitudeDegreeInMeters)}
```

and here is the function the display the floorPlan on google Maps

```
-(void) setGroundOverlay {

overlay2.map = nil;

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = floorPlan.center ;
float pixelsToMeters = floorPlan.pixelToMeterConversion;
float heightForCoordinates = floorPlan.height/2 ;
float widthForCoordinates = floorPlan.width/2;

float metersHorizontal = widthForCoordinates * pixelsToMeters;
float metersVertical = heightForCoordinates * pixelsToMeters;

NSArray *lengths = [self calculateLongLatDegreesInMeters:center.latitude];

double longitudes = (double)metersHorizontal / [[lengths objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
double latitudes = (double)metersVertical / [[lengths objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - latitudes, center.longitude - longitudes);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + latitudes, center.longitude + longitudes);

GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:southWestCoordinates coordinate:northEastCoordinates];

// Resize the floorplans so that they work with Google Maps SDK GMSGroundOverlay
UIImage *icon = [self imageWithImage:fpImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(4000, 4000)];
overlay2 = [GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithBounds:overlayBounds icon:icon];
overlay2.bearing = floorPlan.bearing;
overlay2.map = map;}
```

and here is the last function to resize the floor plan image

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)oldImage scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[oldImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;}
```